# facebook likebox show more not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

ive been looking at a few questions over the net with no luck. I have the plugin likebox from facebook for a client who want to use that as their main source of news.

heres the website

```
http://114.23.32.240/~wwwturbo/manawatu-turbos/index.php/news
```

Its working fine however when you scroll down to the Show More button, click that it doesnt show anymore feeds it just goes to a blank page here

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox/stream
```

is there anyway to fix this so it loads more posts? even if I can edit the code to go to their facebook page.

Thanks

Comment: looks like a platform bug

Comment: Do you or anybody know how to fix the platform bug

Comment: Looks like they fixed it; "show more" seems to have disappeared and instead you can keep scrolling down back in time...